# How do you use Drush to import a bunch of users via a csv file from the command line terminal?

Tags: 8, users, drush, importing-exporting

I have a csv file of users and I would like to use the "drush user-create" command to create an account with these users and have them blocked by default with no password.

I noticed that there is a --pipe option, but I'm unsure how to use this with drush user-create to consume a csv file.

My csv file is just an email and the state:

```
peter@yahoo.com,ny
sally@gmail.com,nj
howard@bl.com,oh
billy@yes.com,wy
```

Comment: You should consider using the migrate module for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with this:

```
awk -F "," '{cmd="drush -y ucrt " $1 ">> output"; system(cmd)}' users.csv
```

But it wouldn't work if you have thousands of users as it takes at least a second to create one. And also I can't seem to see the output when the user account is created. Not sure why "output" isn't working. But overall it works if you need to do it like that.

- -F stands for field separator
- The single quote starts the awk language
- cmd is the command variable u designate
- system is where you run the variable *cmd*
- users.csv is the file.